# Named scope in Sunspot search in rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, solr, sunspot-rails

i am using the Sunspot search from multiple models which are tagged under a name.

```
Sunspot.search(Article,Blogpost) do with :tag_ids, params[:id] end
```

How to apply named_scoped like recent ,popularity which are common for all of the 2 models inthe Sunspot search in rails3

Answer (score 0):

Write an ActiveSupport::Concern which you include in both models which delegates to Sunspot